# TypeScript doesnt understand "$location.$$path"?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

is there any reason why Typescript doesnt understand **$location.$$path** ??

Here is a fragment of my controller:

```
    static $inject: string[] = ["DataService", "$location", "$route", "$routeParams", "$log"];

    constructor(
        private dataService: DataService,
        private $location: ng.ILocationService,
        private $route: ng.route.IRouteService,
        private $routeParams: IRouteParams,
        private $log: ng.ILogService) {

        if ($location.$$path.includes("Reports")){

        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. The `$$` properties are private internal properties not meant for use by developers. You can just do `$locaton['$$path']['includes']('Reports')`

Comment: thanks! that will do !!